# Calculating double integral via lebegue technique

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

I heard that one of the drawback of Riemann integral is;it is very laborious to find Riemann integral in higher dimensions e.g Calculating Riemann integral of bounded function $f:D\subset\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,where $D$ is compact domain of $\mathbb{R^2}$.We can find it but it will require more work,and technically it is much difficult.As we know in lebesgue integration,we do partition of range rather than domain as we do in Riemann integration,and therefore lebesgue integration is believe to be easier to apply in case of higher dimensions rather than Riemann integral.

But to calculate integral of $f:D\subset\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is same as double integral and I never saw any lebesgue approach to double or triple integral.

**My question**:Can we actually find double integral via lebegue's technique of integration?Is this technique easier as observed by me?If it is so then why don't I see lebesgue's technique to calculate double integral

Comment: Basically there is no "Lebesgue technique" but rather useful results from Lebesgue's integration theory that allows you to work out integration of a more general class of functions and to manipulate limits and integrals (also other operators) at the same time. Take a look at Folland's book on real analysis and modern techniques, there is a chapter on integration in several variables. I hope this helps :)

Comment: @Homieomorphism,...but you agree that lebesgue integration is possible in calculating double or triple integral,right?Then why don't we study such techniques to calculate it via lebesgue integration?I have always seen Riemann integration technique to calculate double or triple integral.

Comment: well from what I remember of my class in measure theory and integration, the only "techniques" we used were about the use of sequences of functions to approximate the integrand and theorems about how to deal with exchange of limits and integrals. I think it depends on how your prof presents the subject.

Answer (score 1):

We usually use change of variables theorem and Fubini/Tonelli theorem to convert integrals over $\mathbb{R}^n$ to iterated integrals. These are all theorems from measure theory. While they can be stated and proved for the Riemann integral, they will be less general than the corresponding statements for the Lebesgue integral, and the proofs aren't that much easier.